# Local Linear Model with seasonality

Tags: r, time-series, interpretation

I am trying to apply a structural model with seasonality to the famous Airline Passenger data which can be found in R or online.

The following coding in R is being used:

```
 (LL <- StructTS(log10(AirPassengers), type = "BSM"))

The output is:

Variances:
    level      slope       seas    epsilon  
0.0001456  0.0000000  0.0002635  0.0000000
```

Does anyone knows how to interpret this?

From what I have understood the level refers to the transitional variance, the slope refers to the slope variance, seasonal is the seasonal component and epsilon is the observation variance. But I am not sure if this is correct and if the output makes sense or not? how would this be interpreted in state space modelling?